# Flutter Stepper Submit onStepContinue

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stepper

I am wondering how to do 2 things within my Flutter stepper.
Firstly I want to disable the next button until the fields are filled in, secondly, once the fields are filled in and they hit "Next" I want to submit this data to firebase to store what they have submitted

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:worbby/models/task.dart';
import 'package:worbby/services/databaseservice.dart';

class PostTaskScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PostTaskScreenState createState() => _PostTaskScreenState();
}

class _PostTaskScreenState extends State<PostTaskScreen> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _budgetController = TextEditingController();

  int _currentStep = 0;
  double _sliderValue = 5;
  bool _isLoading = false;
  bool _isMorning = false;
  bool _isAfternoon = false;
  bool _isEvening = false;
  String _title, _desc, _location = '';
  StepperType stepperType = StepperType.vertical;

  DateTime _date = DateTime.now();
  TextEditingController _dateController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // _budgetController.addListener(_sliderValue);
  }

  void _selectDate() async {
    final DateTime newDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: _date,
      firstDate: DateTime.now(),
      lastDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 90)),
      helpText: 'Select date for task',
    );
    if (newDate != null) {
      setState(() {
        _date = newDate;
        _dateController.text =
            DateFormat("E, d MMM yyyy").format(_date).toString();
      });
    }
  }

  _submit() async {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate() && !_isLoading) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();

      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });

      // Create task
      // String imageUrl = await StorageService.uploadPost(_image);

      Task task = Task(
          title: _title,
          desc: _desc,
          due: _dateController.text,
          budget: _sliderValue);
      // Database update
      DatabaseService.createPost(task);
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Post a task'),
        bottom: PreferredSize(
            child: Container(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              height: 3.0,
            ),
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(4.0)),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Container(
          child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Stepper(
                type: StepperType.horizontal,
                physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                currentStep: _currentStep,
                onStepTapped: (step) {
                  if (step > _currentStep) {
                    setState(() {
                      _currentStep = step;
                    });
                  }
                },
                // onStepTapped: (step) => tapped(step),
                onStepContinue: continued,
                onStepCancel: cancel,
                controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                    {VoidCallback onStepContinue, VoidCallback onStepCancel}) {
                  return Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: OutlinedButton(
                          onPressed: onStepCancel,
                          child: Text('Back!'),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                          flex: 2,
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: onStepContinue,
                            child: Text('Next!'),
                          )),
                    ],
                  );
                },
                steps: <Step>[
                  Step(
                    title: Text('Task Details'),
                    content: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          'Task Title',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 10.0,
                          ),
                          child: TextFormField(
                            maxLength: 40,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                // counterStyle: ,
                                // labelText: 'Task Title',
                                hintText: 'Short and snappy!'),
                            validator: (input) => input.length < 6
                                ? 'Must be at least 6 characters'
                                : null,
                            onChanged: (input) => _title = input,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Task Description',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            // horizontal: 30.0,
                            vertical: 10.0,
                          ),
                          child: TextFormField(
                            maxLines: 10,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                // counterStyle: ,
                                // labelText: 'Task Description',
                                hintText:
                                    'Briefly describe what you would like to achieve'),
                            validator: (input) => input.length < 6
                                ? 'Must be at least 6 characters'
                                : null,
                            onChanged: (input) => _desc = input,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    isActive: true,
                    state: _currentStep == 0
                        ? StepState.editing
                        : StepState.complete,
                  ),
                  Step(
                    title: Text('Location'),
                    content: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              vertical: 10.0,
                            ),
                            child: Text(
                              'Where does this task take place?',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
                            )),
                        Text(
                            'For your security, complete address will only visible by the talent you contracted for the task',
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1),
                        Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              // horizontal: 30.0,
                              vertical: 10.0,
                            ),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              maxLines: 1,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  // counterStyle: ,
                                  // labelText: 'Task Description',
                                  hintText: 'Address 1'),
                              validator: (input) => input.length < 6
                                  ? 'Must be at least 6 characters'
                                  : null,
                              onChanged: (input) => _location = input,
                            )),
                        Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              // horizontal: 30.0,
                              vertical: 10.0,
                            ),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              maxLines: 1,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  // counterStyle: ,
                                  // labelText: 'Task Description',
                                  hintText: 'City'),
                              validator: (input) => input.length < 6
                                  ? 'Must be at least 6 characters'
                                  : null,
                              // onSaved: (input) => _password = input,
                            )),
                        Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              // horizontal: 30.0,
                              vertical: 10.0,
                            ),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              maxLines: 1,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  // counterStyle: ,
                                  // labelText: 'Task Description',
                                  hintText: 'State'),
                              validator: (input) => input.length < 6
                                  ? 'Must be at least 6 characters'
                                  : null,
                              // onSaved: (input) => _password = input,
                            )),
                        Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              // horizontal: 30.0,
                              vertical: 10.0,
                            ),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              maxLines: 1,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  // counterStyle: ,
                                  // labelText: 'Task Description',
                                  hintText: 'Postcode'),
                              validator: (input) => input.length < 4
                                  ? 'Must be at least 4 characters'
                                  : null,
                              // onSaved: (input) => _password = input,
                            )),
                      ],
                    ),
                    isActive: _currentStep >= 0,
                    state: _currentStep == 1
                        ? StepState.editing
                        : StepState.disabled,
                  ),
                  Step(
                    title: new Text('Date & Budget'),
                    content: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        TextFormField(
                          controller: _dateController,
                          onTap: _selectDate,
                          enabled: true,
                          // initialValue: DateFormat("E, d MMM yyyy")
                          //     .format(_date)
                          //     .toString(),
                          readOnly: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Date'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 8),
                        Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              vertical: 10.0,
                            ),
                            child: Text(
                              'Time of day?',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
                            )),
                        Center(
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              FilterChip(
                                avatar: Icon(Icons.wb_twighlight),
                                label: Text('Morning'),
                                selected: _isMorning,
                                onSelected: (bool) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _isMorning =
                                        _isMorning == true ? false : true;
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                              FilterChip(
                                avatar: Icon(Icons.wb_sunny),
                                label: Text('Afternoon'),
                                selected: _isAfternoon,
                                onSelected: (bool) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _isAfternoon =
                                        _isAfternoon == true ? false : true;
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                              FilterChip(
                                avatar: Icon(Icons.nights_stay_outlined),
                                label: Text('Evening'),
                                selected: _isEvening,
                                onSelected: (bool) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _isEvening =
                                        _isEvening == true ? false : true;
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Column(children: [
                                Text(
                                  'Budget:',
                                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
                                )
                              ]),
                              Column(children: [
                                TextField(
                                    // _sliderValue.round().toString(),
                                    // controller: _sliderValue.round().toString(),
                                    style:
                                        Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5),
                              ])
                            ]),
                        Slider(
                          value: _sliderValue,
                          min: 5,
                          divisions: 25,
                          max: 500,
                          label: _sliderValue.round().toString(),
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              _sliderValue = value;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    isActive: _currentStep >= 0,
                    state: _currentStep >= 2
                        ? StepState.complete
                        : StepState.disabled,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )),
    );
  }

  tapped(int step) {
    setState(() => _currentStep = step);
  }

  continued() {
    _currentStep < 2 ? setState(() => _currentStep += 1) : null;
  }

  cancel() {
    _currentStep > 0 ? setState(() => _currentStep -= 1) : null;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you tell us what exactly is the problem, are you getting an error, what have you tried, there is something that is not working ?

Comment: I havent been able to work out to submit the form when clicking next or validating the form before going to next step

Comment: and what is the issue that you are facing now, be explicit please :)